# interpolate pandas frame using time index from another data frame

Tags: python, pandas

So, I have 2 data frames where the first one has the following structure:

```
               'ds',             '1_sensor_id',     '1_val_1', '1_val_2'
0    2019-09-13 12:40:00             33469             30               43   
1    2019-09-13 12:45:00             33469             43               43
```

The second one has the following structure:

```
              'ds',                '2_sensor_id', '2_val_1', '2_val_2'


0    2019-09-13 12:42:00             20006             6      50
1    2019-09-13 12:47:00             20006             5      80
```

So what I want to do is merge the two pandas frame through interpolation. So ultimately, the merged frame should have values defined at the time stamps (`ds`) defined in frame 1 and the `2_val_1` and `2_val_2` columns would be interpolated and the merged frame would have a row for each value in `ds` column in frame 1. What would be the best way to do this in pandas? I tried the `merge_asof` function but this does nearest neighbourhood interpolation and I did not get all the time stamps back.

Answer (score 0):

You can `append` one frame to another and use [interpolate()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html), example:

```py
import datetime
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ds', '1_sensor_id', '1_val_1', '1_val_2'],
                   data=[[datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 13, 12, 40, 00), 33469, 30, 43],
                         [datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 13, 12, 45, 00), 33469, 33, 43]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ds', '2_sensor_id', '2_val_1', '2_val_2'],
                   data=[[datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 13, 12, 42, 00), 20006, 6, 50],
                         [datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 13, 12, 47, 00), 20006, 5, 80]])
df = df1.append(df2, sort=False)
df.set_index('ds', inplace=True)
df.interpolate(method = 'time', limit_direction='backward', inplace=True)
print(df)
                     1_sensor_id  1_val_1  ...  2_val_1  2_val_2
ds                                         ...                  
2019-09-13 12:40:00      33469.0     30.0  ...      6.0     50.0
2019-09-13 12:45:00      33469.0     33.0  ...      5.4     68.0
2019-09-13 12:42:00          NaN      NaN  ...      6.0     50.0
2019-09-13 12:47:00          NaN      NaN  ...      5.0     80.0
```